# SSL Handshake and Server Response

Tags: java, http, ssl, tcp, https

I want to know that if the website content change during SSL handshake or TCP handshake what happen?

For example:

The TCP or SSL handshake start exactly at 16:02:00 o'clock between the client and server.And some reason the handshake take a long time.Let's say 5 seconds.

So handshake finish at 16:02:05 with some latency but succesfully.And client start to the take content.

But if the site content change while ssl handshake.For example if it change at 16:02:03 what happen?

- Let's say at 16:02:00 the site content is:  "ABCD" (when ssl or tcp handshake start)
- And at 16:02:03 it changes to: "ABCD1234"(while handshake continue)

So the client get which one of them; "ABCD" or "ABCD1234" ?

And here is the my client side java code for get the server response:

```
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
  URL obj = new URL(url); // url is https
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);
  con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
  con.setReadTimeout(15000);

  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

  InputStream is =    con.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

The server sends the response which is current at the time it opens the response file (or wherever it gets the response from). The full URL is only known after the server received the HTTP request. This request is only done after the SSL handshake inside the established SSL tunnel. Thus it will not serve the version from before the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code included in your post doesn't use clearly SSL, but with SSL, handshake must be done before anything else. No content will be downloaded before handshake is done (and valid) because no request can be done before that. Handskake must be finished to encode and decode correctly the request.

Comment: My url is https and the code use ssl handshake.I can see it in ssl java debug mode.So you say that in my case I get the Inputstream of "ABCD1234".Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, or no. It depends on your server implementation. If old content is in cache or memory, what is changed (the file on disk ?), when you read it (only after request or before ?), etc. But yes, i said that you treat the request only after handshake is finished, and if you start computing the content at this moment (like reading a file), it should include all previous changes until this instant